# Connect Checkpoint Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, vpn, checkpoint

I'm looking information on how to connect checkpoint NGX R60 with Windows XP. I dont have Checkpoint account since I'm only want to connect with it. Is it possible? I've search on google and all gives me result to download Checkpoint NGX Endpoint client for Windows. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this is a dead question, but oh well...

It's not clear what you want to do, there are two possibilities:

If you're trying to connect to your firewall to manage it, you need the GUI client and you'll need an account.  Depending on the configuration, your PC will need a fixed IP address and that IP has to be allowed to connect to the management ports.

If you're trying to get a VPN connection, you need the VPN client and again, you'll need an account.  This might be a standalone account, or your system might be set up to use Radius so that you can use your normal AD account name and password.

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, you need the Checkpoint admin software matching your hardware in order to connect.  The only way I've been able to acquire this software is by logging into their site (and necessarily paying maintenance fees).  This is likely a security feature, as I wouldn't want my users to be a quick download away from attempting to log in, either.

You should probably contact the party who supplied the firewall, as I believe there should have been a disc included with that software.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to connect to a Chechpoint VPN, you need the client software you mentioned.
If you want to manage the firewall, you need the mgmt software, which comes with the installation CDs for the firewall itself, or can be downloaded from the website, if you have a paid account